java.lang.ClassNotFoundException in GraalVM Executable
i want to auto-build a Java 8 Executable first into a standalone-jar then produce a Windows executable (on GitHub Actions)
Weird thing is that my local build with the same Liberica NIK Version produces a working executable, but the .exe file i get from Github spills out
Error: Could not find or load main class de.teatime08.Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.teatime08.Main

even thought the .jar file which is used for producing the exe is always running.
I already have tried different configurations for Graal and also the maven-assembly-plugin producing the jar.
But cannot find the reason i get the error.
My current settings are:
pom.xml:
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <!--<addClasspath>true</addClasspath>-->
                <!--<classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>-->
                <mainClass>de.teatime08.Main</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

the github workflow important parts:
name: GraalVM SimpleInternetMonitor builds
on: [push, pull_request]
jobs:
  build:
    name: SimpleInternetMonitor on ${{ matrix.os }}
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    strategy:
      matrix:
        os: [windows-latest]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      # Setup the GraalVM with liberica, to avoid executing UI triggers
      - uses: graalvm/setup-graalvm@v1
        with:
          java-version: '21'
          distribution: 'liberica'
          # distribution: 'graalvm-community'
          java-package: 'jdk+fx'
          github-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          native-image-job-reports: 'true'
          cache: 'maven'

      # Execute the build script
      - name: Build
        run: |
          .\buildNative_from_Windows.ps1

      - name: Upload Java Executable file
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: SimpleInternetMonitor.jar
          path: target\SimpleInternetMonitor.jar

      - name: Upload Executable
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: SimpleInternetMonitor.exe
          path: target-native\SimpleInternetMonitor.exe

and the build script:
mvn -B -ntp clean install compile -Pnative package "-Djava.awt.headless=false" "-Dmaven.tests.skip=true" "-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=WARN"
echo "Creating target-native dir"
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path target-native
echo "Starting Native Build on Windows."
native-image `
    -g -O0 `
    "-Djava.awt.headless=false" `
    --link-at-build-time `
    --enable-http `
    --enable-https `
    "-H:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions" `
    "-H:ResourceConfigurationFiles=native-resources-configuration.json" `
    -jar .\target\SimpleInternetMonitor.jar `
    .\target-native\SimpleInternetMonitor

I was trying this already:

switching between liberica and graal-community version
changing the pom.xml <!--<addClasspath>true</addClasspath>--><!--<classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>-->
changing the maven build command -Pnative or native:compile
trying out compiling with JDK Version 8, which didn't work
call native-compile with --no-fallback --allow-incomplete-classpath --report-unsupported-elements-at-runtime
see other tries at my Github Branch Commits

Update
I think this is because the images instantly tries to run on fallback mode, which means it does not try to run the image natively, but tries to run (parts?) with a system installed JRE.
I now switched to the --no-fallback native-image mode to avoid this. Not having the issue any longer in this mode.

Did you try and adding de.teatime08.Main to your path or include the complete path to the class ?

Inside the jar, the de/teatime08/Main.class is availible.
